# MongoDb return a UTC DateTime when I stored a Local DateTime by C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-.net-driver

MongoDb: 3.2 x64
C# driver: Official C# driver 2.2

After I have written a instance of TestClass, and retrieve it afterwards. I find the field "DataTime" has been changed into UTC DateTime.

Of course I know c# driver write DateTime with UTC format, but it is so wired to convert it to UTC automatically and do nothing when I retrieve it from mongo.

I used "samus" driver before which convert DateTime to UTC format while writing to mongo and converting to Local DateTime while you retrieve it.

Here is the test codes:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

using MongoDB;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://root:root@127.0.0.1");
            var db = client.GetDatabase("Test");
            var col = db.GetCollection<TestClass>("TestClass");

            var data = new TestClass(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            col.InsertOne(data);

            var find = Builders<TestClass>.Filter.Eq("_id", data.DataTime);
            var fo = new FindOptions<TestClass>();
            fo.Limit = 1;
            var t = col.FindSync(find, fo);
            var data_ret = t.ToList()[0];

            Assert.AreEqual(data.Text, data_ret.Text);
            Assert.AreEqual(data.DataTime, data_ret.DataTime);            
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
        }

        public TestClass(string arg_strText)
        {
            DataTime = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Text = arg_strText;
        }   

        [BsonId]
        public DateTime DataTime;
        public string Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you mention, MongoDB always stores datetimes in UTC, so when you read it back, why would you expect anything besides UTC? The fact that the input date was local is lost during the conversion to UTC.

Comment: @JohnnyHK  I supposed to retrieve the staff which equals to what I wrote. So I am confused about the behavior of official driver.    And what samus driver does matches the "equal" ruler.

Comment: Sure, but you understand what's going on, right? And the assert on `DataTime` would fail even if you were using a `UtcNow` value because the C# time has a higher resolution than a BSON Date. So there's a lot going on here. The samus driver hasn't been updated in 6 years, so that's not exactly a good reference. :-)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB store only UTC-Data. So either you could take care yourself to convert it, or you could tell the driver that you want to work with local datetime, the driver will than do it for you (convert to utc on storing and back on reading). For that you need to register predefined `Serializer`

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTime),
                         new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Local));
```

Comment: If the data is written by an application running the mongodb driver in america and the data is then read by an application running in asia I assume the originating write TZ is lost?